# Print the contents of a HashMap in sorted order according to the Size of each HashMap nested inside the given HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` inside a `HashMap`. I want to print the elements in the `HashMap` according to the size of elements in the inner `HashMap`. So the element with the highest number of elements should print first. I'm new to HashMaps and got stuck.

This is the `HashMap` and how I'm printing it:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> states = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

for(Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : states.entrySet()) {

    System.out.println("State:" + entry.getKey());

    Map<String, Integer> tempMap = entry.getValue();

    for(Entry<String, Integer> innerEntry : tempMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("City:" + innerEntry.getKey() + " Count:" + innerEntry.getValue());
    }
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output that I'm currently getting:

```
State:Texas
City:Austin Count:1

State:Hawaii
City:Honolulu Count:1
City:Kihei Count:1
City:Maui Count:1

State:California
City:Newport Beach Count:1
```

The output I need:

```
State:Hawaii
City:Honolulu Count:1
City:Kihei Count:1
City:Maui Count:1

State:Texas
City:Austin Count:1

State:california
City:Newport Beach Count:1
```

Comment: Without changing the nature of the problem, just about the only thing you can do is a nested loop where you find the largest inner-map, print it out, remove it from the outer-map, and continue. Then you can add back every map at the end.

Comment: You can't sort a hash map. This is a job for streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` is not capable of maintaining the order, therefore you can't sort it.

You can dump the map contents into a list and sort it using a custom comparator. But there's something that you're missing - the way you're structuring the data is wrong, *state* and *cities* that belong to that *state* are two pieces of information are closely related to each other. Using a map to combine them together is an abuse of collections, it makes your code rigid and unmaintainable.

#### Use the power of Objects

Your code doesn't become object-oriented automatically because of the fact that you're using an object-oriented language.

The correct approach would be to define `State` and `City` as classes and maintain a list of `State` objects instead of dealing with a nested *map*.

```
class State {
    private String name;
    private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public State(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void addCity(City city) {
        cities.add(city);
    }
    
    public boolean removeCity(City city) {
        return cities.remove(city);
    }
    
    public List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "State:" + name + "\n" +
            cities.stream()
                .map(City::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
            + "\n";
    }
}

class City {
    private String name;
    private int count;
    
    public City(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City:" + name + " Count:" + count;
    }
}
```

That's how you can use this classes in the client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();
    State texas = new State("Texas");
    texas.addCity(new City("Austin", 1));
    
    State hawaii = new State("Hawaii");
    hawaii.addCity(new City("Honolulu", 1));
    hawaii.addCity(new City("Kihei", 1));
    hawaii.addCity(new City("Maui", 1));
    
    State california = new State("California");
    california.addCity(new City("Newport Beach", 1));
    
    Collections.addAll(states, texas, hawaii, california);
    
    states.sort(Comparator.<State>comparingInt(state -> state.getCities().size()).reversed());
    
    for (State state: states) {
        System.out.println(state);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
State:Hawaii
City:Honolulu Count:1
City:Kihei Count:1
City:Maui Count:1

State:Texas
City:Austin Count:1

State:California
City:Newport Beach Count:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since *ConcurrentHashMap* makes no guarantees about ordering, you have to sort your map be getting entrySet and sort them then re-put into a *LinkedHashMap*

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> sortedStates = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
states.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapA, Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapB){
                return mapB.getValue().size() - mapA.getValue().size();
              }
            })
        .forEachOrdered(mapInner -> sortedStates.put(mapInner.getKey(), mapInner.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. create a size_map -> Map<Integer, List> size_map = new HashMap<Integer, List>();

- This is to store store number of cities as key and states as the value. Note here states are stored in a list because multiple states can have same number of cities.

2. Make a list (size_list) out of keys of map in point 1. (Keys are number of cities for different states). Order this list in descending order
3. While iterating your "states" Hashmap, use size_list as a lookup and fetch the list of states with the current size from size_map HashMap. Basically use size_list as a lookup.

Note - this will increase your overhead and performance might not be great.

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> states = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

    //create size HashMap -- store number of cities as key and value would be list of states 
    Map<Integer, List<String>> size_map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : states.entrySet())
    {
        int size = entry.getValue().size();
        String state = entry.getKey();
        if(size_map.containsKey(size))
        {
            List<String> retreived_list = size_map.get(size);
            retreived_list.add(state);
            size_map.put(size, retreived_list);
        }
        else
        {
            List<String> retreived_list = new ArrayList<String>();
            retreived_list.add(state);
            size_map.put(size, retreived_list);
        }
    }

    //create a list out of size_map keys and sort it in descending order
    List<Integer> size_list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size_map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(size_list, Collections.reverseOrder());

    //index will be current index in size_list, fetch states list from size_map and look for the same state in the original "state" hashmap
    int index =0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : states.entrySet())
    {
        int current_size = size_list.get(index);
        List<String> states_list = size_map.get(current_size);

        for(String s : states_list)
        {
            System.out.println("State:" + s);
            Map<String, Integer> tempMap = states.get(s);
            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> innerEntry : tempMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("City:" + innerEntry.getKey() + " Count:" + innerEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
        index++;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Streams API for sorting before print it out:

```
Comparator<Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>>> entryComparator =
        Comparator.comparingInt((Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entryOne) -> entryOne.getValue().size());

    for(Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> entry : states.entrySet().stream().sorted(entryComparator.reversed()).collect(
        Collectors.toList())) {
      System.out.println("State:" + entry.getKey());
      Map<String, Integer> tempMap = entry.getValue();
      for(Entry<String, Integer> innerEntry : tempMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("City:" + innerEntry.getKey() + " Count:" + innerEntry.getValue());
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.
Using LinkedHashMap instead and that will look like:

```
Map sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
originalHashMap.entrySet().stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size()))
     .forEachOrdered(e -> sortedMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Now, expected sorted map is sortedMap

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> states = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
states.put("Texas", Map.of("Austin", 1));
states.put("Hawaii", Map.of("Honolulu", 1, "Kihei", 1, "Maui", 1));
states.put("California", Map.of("Newport Beach", 1)); 

states.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue().size()))
    .forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println("State:" + e.getKey());
        e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(f -> System.out.println("City:" + f.getKey() + " Count:" + f.getValue()));
        System.out.println();
    });
```

output:

```
State:Hawaii
City:Maui Count:1
City:Honolulu Count:1
City:Kihei Count:1

State:Texas
City:Austin Count:1

State:California
City:Newport Beach Count:1
```